# Explain the term 'First-class functions' in relation to Javascript

Tags: javascript, first-class-functions

Can someone explain this term for me and describe a typical programming situation where first-class functions are used?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Could you explain what you don't understand when you searched up "first-class functions"? Also what do you need to do this for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We often hear that JavaScript functions are first-class functions, meaning both functions and objects are treated by the language as the same thing. In practical terms, a function can be stored as a variable, inside an array or an object, as well as it can be passed as an argument or be returned by another function. That makes functions “first-class citizens” in JavaScript.

These are the examples:

```
var myfunc2 = function(a)
{
 return a + 1;
};

var myfunc2 = function myfunc4(a)
{
 return a + 1;
};
```

Refer the following links

http://odiseo.net/javascript/first-class-functions-in-javascript-how-comes-functions-are-treated-as-objects-in-js

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84433/first-class-functions/